# How do I configure git to do push with my user to GitHub?

Tags: git, github

When I do commits and push from command line, git push that commit to github but that commit it's not from my github user. When I do it from intellij github requires username and password and all commits are linked to my account. How can I configure it ?

Answer (score 0):

I found this example [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup):

```
$ git config --global user.name "John Doe"
$ git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com
```

You'll also need to set up an SSH key on your local machine. [Here's](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/) how to get that done.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ssh/git protocol and you will not to use password any more.

Here is how to set it up:

- Generate a new ssh key (or skip this step if you already have a key)
  `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your@email"`
- Once you have your key set in `home/.ssh` directory (or `Users/<your user>.ssh` under windows), open it and copy the content

---

#### How to add sh key to github account?

- Login to github account
- Click on the rancher on the top right (Settings)
  [image]
- Click on the `SSH keys`
  [image]
- Click on the `Add ssh key`
  [image]
- Paste your key and save

And you all set to go :-)